# How to disable other image when 2 image select out of 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my website i want to add one feature to disable other image when user select 2 images. 
In my website, i have 5 images. Form this 5 image user select max 2 no. of images.
When user select 2 images other 3 images are disable automatically.

Answer (score 2):

See my demo on snippet.This is your answer, Hopefully it sends you in the right direction. Change js according to your need.Here I set length maximum 2.

```
 if (+$("input[name=ItemGrp2]:checked").length > 2)
```

Use this code.

```js
$( ".two" ).on( "change", function() {   
    if (+$("input[name=ItemGrp2]:checked").length > 2)
    {
        this.checked=false;
    }    
            
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type="checkbox"][id^="cb"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label:before {
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transform: scale(0);
}

label img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

:checked + label {
  border-color: #ddd;
}

:checked + label:before {
  content: "✓";
  background-color: grey;
  transform: scale(1);
}

:checked + label img {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input class="two" name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" id="cb1" />
    <label for="cb1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" /></label>
  </li>
  <li><input class="two" name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" id="cb2" />
    <label for="cb2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/101/101" /></label>
  </li>
  <li><input class="two" name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" id="cb3" />
    <label for="cb3"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/102/102" /></label>
  </li>
  <li><input class="two" name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" id="cb4" />
    <label for="cb4"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/103/103" /></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting the answer [(see How to accept SO answers)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) and upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you [(see How to upvote on Stack Overflow?)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var $form = $('.form');

var $imgInputs = $form.find('.img-cb');
  
$imgInputs.on('change', function () {
    var isMaxSelected = ($imgInputs.filter(':checked').length >= 2);
    $imgInputs.not(':checked').prop('disabled', isMaxSelected);
});
```

```css
.img-cb {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.img-cb:disabled + img {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.img-cb:checked + img {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" class="form">
        <label>
            <input class="img-cb" type="checkbox">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150" alt="">
        </label>
        <label>
            <input class="img-cb" type="checkbox">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150" alt="">
        </label>
        <label>
            <input class="img-cb" type="checkbox">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150" alt="">
        </label>
        <label>
            <input class="img-cb" type="checkbox">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150" alt="">
        </label>
        <label>
            <input class="img-cb" type="checkbox">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150" alt="">
        </label>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an event listener which increments a counter initialized to zero upon clicking an image, but only if the counter is not >=2. Also push the ids of the photos clicked (the object is passed along the event anyway)

If counter reaches 2, use jQuery/ native Javascript to hide the photos not in the id list. (This would require a continuous sequence of ids to be given to the photos and also knowledge of # of photos, which in this case is assumed to be 5 and never change dynamically)